# What software do you use to do algebra operations when the number of operations get out of hand?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-software

I need to solve a 12th degree polynomial with coefficients that are not numbers, but are made out of lots of algebra operations with letters. I could do them all by hand, but I counted them and it would take me around 7000 algebra operations do to so. Since this task can easily be automated I'm wondering what tools do professionals use to check their algebra?

Edit: And please dont tell me that 12 degree polynomials cant be solved, because I know all about Galois groups.

Comment: I‘d use a CAS like Maple

Comment: @Wuestenfux thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Mathematica works OK too

Comment: You can probably do it with sage, which is free (unlike Mathematica or Maple).

Comment: Really large pieces of paper.

Comment: @copper.hat You jest, but long, long ago, before computers... I can't imagine the absolute tonnes of paper Euler, Cantor, Galois, etc used. (Though possibly Cantor was resourceful and used sets of paper with density zero, by just removing the central third of each folio ad infinitum). As to the OP's question: Sagemath is free and easy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is really nice for stuff like that.